# Is numpy.asarray() necessary here?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm following an example in the book "Deep Learning with Python" by Francois Chollet.
There's an example (pg 70) where they convert an array of int's to an array of float32

The relevant lines are

```
from keras.datasets import imdb
(tr_data, tr_labels), (ts_data, ts_labels) = imdb.load_data(num_words=10000)
...
import numpy as np
y_train = np.asarray(tr_labels).astype('float32')
```

tr_labels is simply an array of ints

```
array([1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0])
```

y_train is an array of float32

```
array([1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 1., 0.], dtype=float32)
```

But why do we need to call np.asarray() when simply this seems to do the trick

```
y_train = tr_labels.astype('float32')
```

Just wondering if numpy.asarray() does some additional data processing I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not necessary.

`np.asarray` is sometimes useful if you aren't sure what the datatype is (or if it can change), and it won't make a copy into a new array if the input is already an `ndarray`, so it shouldn't be a slowdown if `tr_labels` is already an array. Along a similar vein, if you want to allow subclasses of `ndarray` you can use `np.asanyarray` which will pass through any subclass of `ndarray` (such as sparse arrays, etc.) without extra copying. These are just two examples of the many [array creation functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-creation.html#from-existing-data) numpy provides from existing data. There are often multiple right answers, but sometimes one may be more efficient (memory wise) than another.